# Should I have been returning a promise all along?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have been calling a method MediaNext() from several points in my PlayersController code to chain the next Media playback if any.

- This MediaNext() method returns a Media object from some of the various playlists I have from memory.  So it tries to encapsulate the notion of getting the next Media object if any left.
- However, recently I revised MediaNext() that for some new condition X I now have to load external data in order to return this alternative Media object.

```
MediaNext():any {  // any could be typed like Media_I
   if(cond1) {
      ...
      return Media1
    }
   if(cond2) {
      ...
      return Media1
    }
    //
    if(! AutoPlayNext) return null;
    //
    if(NoMoreMedia) return null;
    //
    If (condX) {
      // in order to wait for the Load() method I am subscribing to its promise
      this.Service1.Load(Media).then(() => {
         ...processing...
         return Media
      })
      ??? what do I return here, it does not make sense to return null, since potentially a Media is on its way ???
    }
    return null // safe catch. nomore media should not happen.
}
```

The questions I have

1. By subscribing to the promise of the .Load(), the execution from what I gather in JS should not be blocked waiting for the media data to return.  Instead the execution needs to flow and the call to MediaNext() has to return.  However, what could I be returning where indicated in the code above "???".
2. Should MediaNext() have been coded to return a promise for all conditions?

I mostly do guess work when I code promises and observables as they remain a beast to understand and master so feel free to advise alternatives.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, return a promise from `mediaNext()`

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with `.Load` asynchronously and immediately return, there's no good reason for that function to return anything. The operation is still happening in the backend.

However, if you want the caller to get more information about if the operation was successful or not, you should return a promise.

If you want to return a promise, you might find it much easier to write this as an async function, and use `await this.Service1.Load()`. instead of `then()`.

Answer (score 0):

You method is now asynchronous and you are using a Promise. You then need to return a promise which your consumers can wait on to get a result. Either:

1) Return the promise

```
    If (condX) {
      return this.Service1.Load(Media);
    }
```

2) Set your method as async and await the promise used internally

```
async MediaNext():any {  // any could be typed like Media_I
    // ...

    If (condX) {
      return await this.Service1.Load(Media);
    }

    // ...
```